# Ifttt filter replace string

Tags: javascript, ifttt

I have url encode with `&amp;`

```
https://myurl.c/photo.jpg?width=1000px&amp;height=500px&amp;compress=none
```

inside ifttt filter use javascript filter I need replace & into &

```
var foto = GoogleSheets.newRowInSpreadsheet.ColumnG;
var res = foto.replace(/&amp;/g, '&');
Telegram.sendPhoto.setPhotoUrl(res);
Telegram.sendPhoto.setCaption(res);
```

I need put the image url and post into telegram from google sheet.

but the problem my replace code & into & never work. please help. thanks